# Array is empty outside the function, trying to fetch data from database, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to build an application with Ionic Framework and Javascript, and I want to fetch all the data from a table in an array, but when I try to access that array outside the function it's empty. I've read something that maybe the array gets populated after the `console.log("length "+ $scope.cards.length);` but I don't know how to solve this so I can use the array after that.

This is the function for fetching the data from the table(it works):

```
 fetchCards: function(success) {
  database.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT cardId, name, chosen, filePath, found FROM Cards", [], 
      function (tx, results) {
        console.log('success select ' + results);
        cards = [];
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
          cards.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        success(cards);
      }, 
      function () {
        console.log('error select');
      });
  });
}
```

This is where I try to access the array, in a controller:

```
    .controller('kindergartenController', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate,service) {

     //list with the difficulties
     $scope.difficultyList=[
     {text:"Easy", value:"easy"},
     {text:"Medium", value:"medium"},
     {text:"Hard", value:"hard"}];

     $scope.data={difficulty:''};

    //redirecting if it presses 
    $scope.goToAnimalsGame = function() {


    if($scope.data.difficulty=='easy'){
      window.location = "#/menu/animalseasy";

      //in this array I want the results
      $scope.cards=[];

      game = new Game(1,"easyAnimalGame");
      console.log("created a new game " + game.getName());
      game.createMemoryGame();

      console.log("difficulty " + $scope.data.difficulty);
      randomNumbers=game.randomNumbers($scope.data.difficulty);
      console.log('Random numbers are:');
      for(i=0;i<randomNumbers.length;i++){
        console.log(randomNumbers[i]);
      }

      //here is where I call the other function, to get data from database
      service.fetchCards(function(cards) {
        $scope.cards = cards;
      //it shows the good length
        console.log("length "+ $scope.cards.length);
      });
      //it shows it's empty
      console.log("length "+ $scope.cards.length);
}
```

Any suggestions are helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show empty because:

`service.fetchCards`

is Asynchronous, therefore inside that function where you define your anonymous callback, won't fire till the data is retrieved.

the `console.log("length "....` outside of the function will be executed immediately after the function call `fetchCards`, but possibly before the callback where the array gets populated.

Unfortunately you can only deal with the populated array within the callback or from a function fired within the callback.

Here is a timeline of execution to aid:

`service.fetchCards();`

->

`console.log("length "....)` below the above function

->

`anonymous callback (function (cards){})` inside the `service.fetchCards()`

If that makes sense.

The asynchronism of the service means that the callback you defined anonymously could fire at any time.

The solution:

```
service.fecthCards(function (data) {
    // do your code
    $scope.cards = cards;
    //it shows the good length
    console.log("length "+ $scope.cards.length);

    // manipulate the array within this function or get it to call another function like so
    nowContinue();
});

function nowContinue() {
    // continue what ever it was that you wanted to do using the newly populated information
}
```

Because `nowContinue` is called with in the anonymous callback it will fire whenever the callback gets fired, and will execute after you have populated the controllers local variables with data.